# git error: cannot initialize work tree

Tags: git

I'm trying to download a special Android TV AOSP code from its repo.
I run the repo init

```
repo sync -fc -j8
```

command as usual but after fetching all the stuff I always get the following error message.

```
.
.
Fetching projects:  98% (431/439)  Fetching project platform/vendor/widevine
Fetching projects: 100% (439/439), done.  
Syncing work tree:  97% (426/439)  error: unable to read sha1 file of x86_64/vmlinux-qemu (11819c0a8aefd3cb8d0e87884ff44abda7bba2ad)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mehmet/l_mrl-tv-dev-avko/.repo/repo/main.py", line 531, in <module>
_Main(sys.argv[1:])
File "/home/mehmet/l_mrl-tv-dev-avko/.repo/repo/main.py", line 507, in _Main
    result = repo._Run(argv) or 0
File "/home/mehmet/l_mrl-tv-dev-avko/.repo/repo/main.py", line 180, in _Run
    result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
File "/home/mehmet/l_mrl-tv-dev-avko/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 762, in Execute
    project.Sync_LocalHalf(syncbuf, force_sync=opt.force_sync)
File "/home/mehmet/l_mrl-tv-dev-avko/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1246, in Sync_LocalHalf
    self._InitWorkTree(force_sync=force_sync)
File "/home/mehmet/l_mrl-tv-dev-avko/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2387, in _InitWorkTree
    raise GitError("cannot initialize work tree")
error.GitError: cannot initialize work tree
```

It downloads about 30GB data and I have tried many things,

I updated git version, erased ~/l_mrl-tv-dev-avko/.repo/repo directory and vmlinux-qemu file etc. Then made checkout again but nothing changed.

What could be the solution?
Regards

Comment: Deleting the directories you mentioned in the post worked for me. Don't know what else could be causing this.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 I received this error while syncing Android Studio source from android.googlesource.com. The issue kept presenting itself despite deleting various files and trying again until I chose to create C:\src and mount it to /src/ within my Git Bash window. After I did that everything sync'd perfectly.